# error 3464 data type mismatch in criteria expression

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a continuous form in ms access 2010 which is filtered by a textbox in which the user inputs a number.  The filtered field in the underlying data table is of data type number, which also reads Long Integer in table design view.  I assume the textbox delivers a string, so my after update method for the textbox converts the textbox.Value to a numeric format before setting the filter parameter code.  The problem is that every way I try to cast the filterval variable results in a different error.  Casting filterval as Long results in error 3464 data type mismatch in criteria expression at the line:

```
    .Filter = "[ClientNumber]='" & filterval & "'"
```

How do I change my code so that the after update method can filter the form without error, given that the ClientNumber field in the data table is Long Integer?  Here is my current code for the after update method of the txtFilter textbox:

```
Dim filterVal As Long
filterval = CLng(txtFilter.Value)
With Forms!Main!NavigationSubform.Form!NavigationSubform.Form 
    .Filter = "[ClientNumber]='" & filterval & "'"
    .FilterOn = True
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `[ClientNumber]` is Long Integer, don't enclose *filterval* with quotes when you build the `.Filter` string.

```vb
.Filter = "[ClientNumber]=" & filterval
```

And actually, you shouldn't need that *filterval* variable.  Try it this way instead ...

```
.Filter = "[ClientNumber]=" & Me.txtFilter.Value
```

Comment: I would like to test your code change and give feedback, but the form is invisible in Form view even though it is visible in Design view.  The other forms selected by the other tabs in the navigation subform are visible when their tabs are clicked.  Only this form is invisible when its tab is clicked.  This just occurred a few moments ago, and is not changed by closing all other objects or closing and reopening access.  Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: No, I'm stumped as to why it disappeared.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me.  I am not at a location from which I can upload a blank database template to a file sharing site, so I will have to wait to continue this until I can do that later, unless someone else can show me how to make it visible from the information I am able to type.  Thank you again.